# Django Rest Framework - filters by datetime

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently building an app using Django and django-rest-framework.

My problem is relatively simple, but i got stuck at some point.

Basically, i manage Collection and Collectible objects. A Collectible object is assigned to a Collection. Both object have a field "created_at".

I would like to generate a view containing all Collections and for each, all Collectible. It works easily.

Now, i'm looking to generate the very same structure but with a filtering param "createdfrom" to have the new Collections and new Collectibles from the provided date.

Here is the code I have using django-filters:

```
class CollectionFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    # /api/collections/?createdfrom=2013-11-20
    createdfrom = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(name="collectibles__created_at", lookup_type='gt')
    class Meta:
        model = Collection
```

This works almost great. There is only a couple of issues:

- It displays all Collectibles from a Collection in which at least one of them match the filter (basically, it also displays the outdated items along with the news ones)
- It doesn't show new Collections created after such date.

Could anyone help me ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you need a suggestion where you do a Model.objects.filter(created_date__gte=your_date_object)? 
You can include this in the view if a GET parameter exists.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, both the Collection and Collectible must have a date > the date provided for the filter. Thus, we will define an "action" to be taken with the QuerySet and value once provided. This is outlined in the [django-filter documentation covering Core Arguments (specifically `action`)](https://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/filters.html#action).

```
def action(queryset, value):
    return queryset.filter(
        collectibles__created_at__gt=value,
        created_at__gt=value,
    )

class CollectionFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    # /api/collections/?createdfrom=2013-11-20
    createdfrom = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(
        name="collectibles__created_at",
        action=action,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Collection
```

We created an `action` function definition to be called with the QuerySet as the first argument, and the value (date) as the second argument.

> **action:** An optional callable that tells the filter how to handle the queryset. It recieves a QuerySet and the value to filter on and should return a Queryset that is filtered appropriately. -[From Documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/filters.html#action)